# Providing Connection String to EntityFramework DbContext at runtime

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, dbcontext

I am looking to provide connection string to Entity Framework DbContext. I dont want to save that into a configuration file.

I have no preference of passing connection string as a constructor paramater when create instances. I can also set it when ever the instance is initiated internally .. say in partial context classs.

Whats the best approach to handle this situation without effecting design time edmx. I googled around couldnt reach a concluding answer.

Just wanted to add: This is model first approach.

Thanks for pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I've always relied on the config file, but you could implement a factory to return your DbContext... mostly for consistency.  The constructor (in EF5) for DbContext takes a connection string as one of the overloads:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467(v=vs.103).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please elaborate a little bit more details. The problem i am having is . The code i have generated for EF has only one constructor. I looked at your link and may be i am understanding wrong here . I dont have any constructor that takes string in a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question and I'm still in search of an elegant solution.

For the time being, I create a partial class for the entities that allows me to expose the base(string nameOrConnectionString) constructor.

E.g.

```
public partial class MyEntities
{
    public MyEntities(bool arbitraryValue) : base("MyConnectionString") { }
}
```

Then in code I create the DBContext using the new constructor
E.g.

```
using (var myEntities = new MyEntities(false))
{
    ....
```